# PHP extended class method requires same signature including object class requirement?

Tags: object-oriented, php

Not sure exactly how to phrase the question succinctly for the title.

I have a collection class that extends another collection class.

The parent collection-class has a method `addMember(someClass $obj)` that adds an object to the collection.

The child collection-class groups objects of the child class of `someclass`, `someClassChild`. I thought that a child class's method's signature would pass muster as long as the signature was the same or required children of the classes the parent required.

E.g. `addMember(someClassChild $obj)`

But I tried it and I'm getting a warning about strict standards.

So then, how to I implement a collection class as a child of another collection class to provide functionality for parent/child base objects?

Comment: possible duplicate of "[Illegal in PHP: Is there an OOP design reason?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/259909/)", "[Liskov principle: violation by type-hinting](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/218217/)"

Answer (score 4):

It's a violation of Liskov's substitution principle. 
Basically any class that uses `SomeClass` must be able to rely on the fact that `addMember` accepts a `SomeClass` or any of its subclasses.
In your example, that's no longer true, because now you have an implementation of `SomeClass` that will cause a fatal error whenever a `SomeClass` object is passed that is not a `SomeClassChild`.

Some languages allow contravariance of method arguments, meaning that a subclass may accept a more general type (rather than more specific like in your example), which makes sense, because any `SomeClass` is also a `SomeSuperClass` if `SomeClass extends SomeSuperClass`. PHP however doesn't support this.

Answer (score 3):

The principle you're looking for is [covariance and contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29) in type hints. To my knowledge, PHP doesn't support it.

Comment: I guess you're right. I was able to work around that by changing the signature to match the parent, and then adding a bit where it uses `if((!$obj instanceof someClassChild) ) return false`